# how to find roots of a function using Newton- Raphson method

Tags: matlab

This is the code I have, I have to create a user defined function using Newton-Raphson method that will return the root, the value of the function evaluated at the root, the estimated error and the number of iterations used.
I am really confused as to why its not working, I am new to MATLAB, so if anyone could help it would be fantastic!
Thanks in advance.

```
 function root=A6ROOTmedina( fun,fund,xi,errtol)
   syms x
   x0=input('intial guess: ')
   fun= input('function: ')
   fund=eval((subs(diff(fun),x,x0)))
   funx= eval((subs((fun),x,x0)))
   errtol=input('error tolerance: ');
   maxiter=input('maximum number of iterations: ');
   iter=0;
   xn=( x0 -(funx/fund))
   perror= 100*abs((xn-x0)./xn);
   for ii=1:maxiter;
     perror= 100*abs((xn-x0)./xn);
     fprintf('percent error:%f\n',perror)
     xn=(x0 -(funx/fund));
   end
   root=xn;

 end
```

Comment: what makes you think its not working? show an example. Also, this is a numerical method, i.e. do not use symbolics math. The entire purpose of this method is not using symbolic math

Comment: `code`>> root=A6ROOTmedina
intial guess: 0

x0 =

     0

function: cos(x)-x
 
fun =
 
cos(x) - x
 

fund =

    -1


funx =

     1

error tolerance: 0.001
maximum number of iterations: 5

xn =

     1

percent error:0.000000
percent error:0.000000
percent error:0.000000
percent error:0.000000
percent error:0.000000

root =

     6

Comment: I posted an example above, can you please help me? I'm new to matlab. @AnderBiguri

Comment: The code is quite wrong: in NR, the step (funx/fund) has tu be computed *every new `nx`*. you can not reuse the variable.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it and it works now! @AnderBiguri